# C# - take method as an argument without specifying args

Tags: c#, reflection, nameof

I have a method that needs to take the function and its owner class as the input arguments and then to proceed with its names with reflection. Of course I could take a couple of `string`s as the input args, so the method would look like this:

```
void Proceed(string className, string methodName)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"{className}.{methodName} called");
  //...
}
```

and would be called like this:

```
Proceed(nameof(Foo), nameof(Foo.Bar));
```

But I wonder if there is any way to avoid writing the `nameof` keyword every time I am trying to call the method. To me something like `Proceed<Foo>(f => f.Bar)` would look a lot nicer.

I suppose this could be solved with expressions. The problem I face is that if method `Bar` has arguments, you have to specify them explicitly when calling the method (which seems excessive in my case where you only going to need *the name of the method* later).

So, the best solution I managed to find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053770/2560087):

```
void Proceed<T>(Expression<Func<T, Action<object, object>>> expression)
{
//...
}
```

Yet it still specifies the argument method's signature in its own args and therefore is not generic enough.

I wonder if there is some way to pass the function as an argument without specifying its arguments (provided I am only going to need its name later, just like `nameof` keyword does).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass an arbitrary method (or delegate) as parameter to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931306/how-to-pass-an-arbitrary-method-or-delegate-as-parameter-to-a-function)

Comment: Like @HansPassant mentioned, you can easily get the member name, but not the type name. I don't see any advantage on using the an expressing tree other than capturing `this`, but at an higher cost, You could write a Roslyn analyzer to ensure the proper arguments are being passed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the usage of an event or delegate.

You can look up more information regarding those 2 online. The idea is that they store some methods with the same arguments so that later it knows what kind of arguments you need to call.

Comment: I think that it would help if you defined the terms here in the answer rather than simply suggesting that the original questioner look up the terms online.  After all, StackOverflow.com is online.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use the [Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx) keyword.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931306/how-to-pass-an-arbitrary-method-or-delegate-as-parameter-to-a-function).

Comment: If you're just going to link to another answer, why didn't you just flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: There is a difference between a duplicate question and a duplicate answer.  See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313277/duplicate-answer-duplicate-question).